# How to reload page on select option Ajax get method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, parameters, laravel-7

I have a list of competitions in my select option,

I need to know how can make this functionality work,

When a user selects a competition the page should reload with the competition data,

This is the select option in my blade

```
<div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col">
         <select name="competition" id="competitionSearch" class="select listing pt-2 pb-2" >
               <option value="">Select Competition</option>
                   @foreach ($allCompetitions as $competition)
                      <option value="{{ $competition->id }}"> {{ $competition->name }}</option>
                   @endforeach
          </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is how it looks like

[image]

this is the ajax get method i have used

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
    $('#competitionSearch').change(function(){
        
        var compid = $(this).val();
            if(compid > 0){
                fetchRecords(compid);
            }
    });
});

function fetchRecords(id){
$.ajax({
    url: 'detailed-registrations/getCompetitionAjax/'+id,
    type: 'get',
  
    success: function(response){
        if (response) {
            //load selected competition here
        }
    }
});
}
```

My routes

```
Route::get('competitions/{competition}/detailed-registrations/getCompetitionAjax/{id}','CompetitionController@getCompetitionAjax');
```

My function in the controller

```
public function getCompetitionAjax($competition, $id, Request $request)
{
   $comp = $this->competitionsRepo->findOrFail($id);

    return redirect(route('competitions.detailed-registrations',$id))->with('comp',$comp);
}
```

I need to know how can i make this functionality work

initially the user will be in a competition page

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/competitions/1/detailed-registrations
```

once he selects the competition 2 redirected to the competition page with the filtered query parameters as

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/competitions/2/detailed-registrations?filters=visible&age=all&gender=all
```

Comment: You should return json for the getCompetitionAjax method and use the response in js

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need an ajax call for redirecting the user to a different page when a competition is selected, you can redirect from javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $('#competitionSearch').change(function(){
        
        var compid = $(this).val();
            if(compid > 0){
                //Redirect the user to the page which will show the selected details
                location = 'competitions/' + id + '/detailed-registrations?filters=visible&age=all&gender=all';
            }
    });
});
```

And then let the Laravel controller method handle the request to the route *competitions.detailed-registrations*